Issues with python web-scraping for a specific td-class text
I can't seem to get the program extract the text from td class="number pp_2 bk_pp nowrap" from the webpage "https://www.racingandsports.com.au/form-guide/thoroughbred/australia/mornington/2024-04-29/R1/enhanced-form". What do I need to change TFO tab text? Note: when the webpage loads there's a minor delay before the numbers appear on the TFO tab.
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import time

# URL of the webpage
url = "https://www.racingandsports.com.au/form-guide/thoroughbred/australia/mornington/2024-04-29/R1/enhanced-form"

# Fetch the webpage content
response = requests.get(url)

# Introduce a 8-second delay
time.sleep(8)

html_content = response.content

# Parse the HTML content
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_content, "html.parser")

# Find all td elements with class="number pp_2 bk_pp nowrap"
td_elements = soup.find_all("td", class_="number pp_2 bk_pp nowrap")

# Extract text from td elements and print
for td in td_elements:
    print(td.text.strip())


Looking at the source of the web page there does not appear to be an entry with that class id. However, on looking again I found 11 elements with class "number pp_2 bk_pp hide nowrap"; is that what you meant to look for?


OldBoy. yes im looking for python to print the text of those 11 elements and having it printed.


if you use requests and BeautifulSoup then using time.sleep(8) seems useless because they can't run JavaScript - so they don't have to wait until JavaScript add elements :)

I check page and it uses javascript to add some values (and classes) but requests and BeautifulSoup can't run JavaScript. You may need Selenium to control real web browser which can run JavaScript.

Please read my previous message again; the class string in your code is incorrect.
